# Using a GitHub organization variable to populate a choice input's options

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to use an org-wide variable in various GitHub actions throughout the organization, to populate the options of a workflow_dispatch's choice input.

From the documentation, it appears this should be possible by setting the variable to a valid JSON string, then using the `fromJSON()` function to unpack it.

**My variable**:
[image]

**My action**:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ENVIRONMENT:
        required: true
        type: choice
        description: "The environment of the deployment"
        options: ${{ fromJSON(vars.ENV_LIST) }}
```

This doesn't work -- when I try to set the branch in the workflow_dispatch GUI to one with this code, it immediately snaps back to the main branch. When I try to run it on the command line with `gh workflow run`, it fails with a 500.

How can I use an org variable to populate the options in a choice input?

Comment: No you can't...